# StreamWriter MVVM C# writes variable address?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

im studying C# and wanted to create a simple registration and loginform in order to practice. Im trying to use MVVM pattern. As it seemed to be easier just to store login data into text file and afterwards read from it for authentification. But a problem occured StreamWriter writes sth like that : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[LoginForm.Andmed.LoginData]

If anyone can tell whats the issues or how to fix i would be very thankful.

the view model:

```
 class LoginVM
{
    public string path = @"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\data.txt";
    private ObservableCollection<LoginData> andmed; // creating ObservableCollection of LoginData data.

    public ObservableCollection<LoginData> Andmed
    {
        get { return andmed; }
        set { andmed = value; }
    }
    public LoginVM()
    {
        this.andmed = new ObservableCollection<LoginData>();

    }

    public void lisaAndmed(string user, string pass)//adds data to ObservableCollection
    {

        this.andmed.Add(new LoginData(user, pass));

    }
    public void salvestaAndmed()//
    {


        StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(path, true); // using streamwriter to save data from the Collection to the path defined
        SW.WriteLine(this.andmed);
        SW.Close();


    }
    public string autendi() // method for later purpose for authentification in login form.
    {
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(path);

        path = SR.ReadToEnd();

        SR.Close();
        return path;
    }
```

properties :

```
namespace LoginForm.Andmed
{
public class LoginData
{

    private string username;
    private string password;


    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; }
    }

    public LoginData(string _username, string _password)
    {

        this.password = _password;
        this.username = _username;


    }
}
```

}

Model view class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    LoginVM mudel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mudel = new LoginVM();

        this.DataContext = mudel;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (user.Text.Length > 0 && pass1.Password == pass2.Password)
        {

           success.Text = "Successfuly registered!" + user.Text;
           error.Text = "";
           mudel.lisaAndmed(user.Text, pass1.Password); // calling the method to add data into obsercablecooll
           mudel.salvestaAndmed(); // now trying to save the data from obsservablecall
        }
        else if (pass1.Password != pass2.Password)
        {
            error.Text = "Passwords arent the same";

        }
        else
        {

            error.Text = "Username incorrect!";

        }
        Logimine logimine = new Logimine();
        logimine.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

Comment: What exceptions are you getting?

Comment: no expections at all, just the info written to the text file is in format > System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[LoginForm.Andmed.LoginData]

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SW.WriteLine(this.andmed);
```

writes a result of `ObservableCollection<T>.ToString()` method call, which is a type name by default, since `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't override `Object.ToString()`.

You have to use any serializer to save and load `ObservableCollection<LoginData>` contents. For example, it could be [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<LoginData>));
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<LoginData>
        {
            new LoginData { Username = "admin", Password = "123" },
            new LoginData { Username = "johndoe", Password = "456" }
        };

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        // serialize
        using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, collection);
        }

        // deserialize
        using (var reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
        {
            var collectionClone = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

Comment: But if i want to add data to "var collection = new ObservableCollection<LoginData> " from textboxes, then i have to create that method into the MainWindows class?

Comment: @user3024888: you already have this method - `salvestaAndmed`. You need to fix it.